# Solving an iterative, implicit Euler method in MATLAB

Tags: pde, finite-difference, differential-equations

I'm trying to solve an iterative problem that includes an implicit (backwards) Euler method to find successive time values for a given function.  The numerical problem is shown here:

$$
\begin{aligned}
\frac{u_{r,s+1}-u_{r,s}}{\Delta t}&+u_{r,s}\frac{u_{r+1,s+1}-u_{r-1,s+1}+u_{r+1,s}-u_{r-1,s}}{4\Delta x}\\
&\quad+\frac{\eta^*_{r+1,s+1}-\eta^*_{r-1,s+1}+\eta_{r+1,s}-\eta_{r-1,s}}{4\Delta x}\\
&=\frac{1}{3}(\alpha x)^2\frac{u_{r+1,s+1}-2u_{r,s+1}+u_{r-1,s+1}-u_{r+1,s}+2u_{r,s}-u_{r-1,s}}{\Delta x^2 \Delta t}\\
&\quad+\alpha^2x\frac{u_{r+1,s+1}-u_{r-1,s+1}-u_{r+1,s}+u_{r-1,s}}{\Delta x\Delta t},
\end{aligned}
$$

where $s$ is the time iteration and $r$ is the location iteration, $x$ is the true location ($x=r\,\Delta x$), and $\alpha$, $\Delta x$, and $\Delta t$ are constants.  The $\eta$ values are already solved, so I need to solve for $u(r,s+1)$.  However, the solution includes values for $u(r-1,s+1)$ and $u(r+1,s+1)$, which requires this to be solved as a system of equations over $r$ for each $s$.  I have boundary conditions of $u$ for all $r$ when $s=1$, as well as u at the first and last $r$ values for all $s$ (i.e. $u(1,s)$ and $u(r_\max,s)$).  I'm not sure what to do from here though to solve for the "interior" $u$ values at $s+1$.

For reference, the original, non-discretized equation is here:

$$
\frac{\partial\overline{u}}{\partial t}+\overline{u}\frac{\partial\overline{u}}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial\eta}{\partial x}=\frac{1}{3}(\alpha x)^2 \frac{\partial^3\overline{u}}{\partial x^2\partial t}+\alpha^2 x\frac{\partial^2 \overline{u}}{\partial x \partial t}.
$$

Comment: Move all `s+1` terms to the left, all others to the right, develop a linear system `A*u=b` for the equations, change the first and last equations (rows) to match your boundary conditions, and solve: `u = A\b`.

Comment: Hi Troy, I don't think I can do that because the second term isn't linear (i.e. it multiplies u(s+1) terms with a u(s) term, so I can't separate all the (s+1) terms from everything else).

Comment: The u_{r,s} terms are all known; therefore, they are simply coefficients.  Thus, the system is linear in the `s+1` terms. (In truth, there is more than likely some linearization at work to make this so since a big problem with momentum equations is the u^2 nonlinearity.  But I suspect this was precluded in a low-Mach number sense to make the problem less difficult to solve.)

Comment: Can you write the (non-discrete) version of the equation? I would also suggest that you type the equation as part of the question. You can use MathJax.

Comment: Is there a reason you want to use an Euler method? You can probably do a similar discretization and throw it to `ode15s`.

Comment: Why does your $x$ derivative involve values at two different times?

Comment: I assume @nicoguaro is referring to the $u_{r,s}$ in the second term. If this were truly implicit, it seems like that should be $u_{r,s+1}$ That wouldn't make your problem any simpler but it would be helpful to understand this equation.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to TroyHaskin, I've realized that this is in reality a linear problem, since the u(s) values are known from the initial conditions, and is therefore easy to solve in Matlab. Thanks to everyone else for help as well.

EDIT: To be more specific, the system can be solved linearly by separating the u(s+1) terms and their coefficients from everything else. The solution takes the form [Aw,Ap,Ae]u = Q, where u = [u(r-1,s+1),u(r,s+1),u(r+1,s+1)]^T.  Because this is a tridiagonal matrix, it can be solved with minimum storage (note that I have changed location r to i and time s to n in my code, just for personal consistency):

```
    A_E = zeros(N,1);
    A_W = zeros(N,1);
    A_P = zeros(N,1);
    Q = zeros(N+1,1);
    Q(1) = u(1,n+1);
    A_P(1) = 1;

    for i = 2:N
        A_W(i) = (-u(i,n)/(4*dx))-(((alpha*x(i))^2)/(3*(dx^2)*dt))+((alpha^2)*x(i)/(dx*dt));
        A_P(i) = (1/dt)+((2*((alpha*x(i))^2))/(3*(dx^2)*dt));
        A_E(i) = (u(i,n)/(4*dx)) - (((alpha*x(i))^2)/(3*(dx^2)*dt)) - ((alpha^2)*x(i)/(dx*dt));
        Q(i) = u(i,n)/dt - (u(i,n)/(4*dx))*(u(i+1,n)-u(i-1,n)) ...
            - (eta(i+1,n+1)-eta(i-1,n+1)+eta(i+1,n)-eta(i-1,n))/(4*dx) ...
            + (((alpha*x(i))^2)/(3*(dx^2)*dt))*(-u(i+1,n)+(2*u(i,n))-u(i-1,n)) ...
            + ((alpha^2)*x(i)/(dx*dt))*(-u(i+1,n)+u(i-1,n));
    end

        %Gaussian Elimination
        for i = 2:N
            A_P(i) = A_P(i) - (A_W(i)*A_E(i-1)/A_P(i-1));
            Q(i) = Q(i) - (A_W(i)*Q(i-1)/A_P(i-1));
        end

        %Back Substitution
        for i = N:-1:2
            u(i,n+1) = (Q(i) - (A_E(i)*u(i+1,n+1)))/A_P(i);
        end
```

Comment: Just a friendly heads up: you should post your solution since this is currently not an answer, and that is frowned upon.

Comment: Fixed.  Thanks for the heads up; I'm new to stack exchange (and compsci in general).